# Foxpro- add an image with dynamic path

Tags: image, ole, foxpro

In FoxPro report writer, how do I add an image where the path of the image is dynamically generated? E.g. the image will be: "C:\images\" + customer + ".bmp".

I've tried adding it to a variable and then reference that variable as the OLE object file path, but it asks for the image when running the report.

I've found other reports that were written in the past, and they reference a variable called "cBitamp". I can't find that variable anywhere in the report. If I open up the FRX file in notepad, I can see the variable and even the path listed (the file is not readable, but some text comes up)- so I am not sure how they have done it previously.

Answer (score 0):

OK I worked it out. You can actually enter an expression as the file path, so in my case, I had something like:

```
"D:\Images\" + ALLTR(customer) + ".BMP"
```

Comment: I would STRONGLY SUGGEST, you do NOT use hard-coded paths, but maybe create a public variable of something like "cImagesPath = 'D:\Images\'" and then build out as cImagesPath + allt( customer) + ".bmp"... Similarly to using data files... Don't lock yourself in early and say oh crud when you need to move things and everything is hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The variable would be in the report anyway, so it is not going make changing the report path any easier.. plus its a very small legacy system (FoxPro.. very old and outdated!) so it's not really a worry for me.

Comment: Old yes ... outdated ... not quite yet.